# How to calculate standard error of sample quantile from normal distribution with known mean and standard deviation?

Tags: standard-error, quantiles

I know that the standard error of the mean for an iid sample is calculated as $$\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

However, assuming a normal distribution with known mean and standard deviation, how do you calculate the standard error of an arbitrary quantile?

For example, assume

- normal distribution
- population mean = 0
- population standard deviation = 1
- n=100
- quantile = .95

What would be the standard error of this quantile?

---

I ran this little simulation to explore the properties, but I'm still interested in the closed form solution:

```
set.seed(1234)
generate_x <- function(n) x <- rnorm(n)
k <- 10000
n <- 100

results <- lapply(seq(k), function(X) generate_x(100))

Z <- seq(.01, .99, .01)
qresults <- sapply(results, function(X) quantile(X, Z))

sd_quresults <- apply(qresults, 1, sd)
var_quresults <- apply(qresults, 1, var)

plot(Z, sd_quresults, type='l')
```

[image]

Comment: This plot looks *remarkably* like the output of `curve(sqrt(x*(1-x)/100) / abs(dnorm(qnorm(x))), 0, 1)` :-).

Comment: @whuber Is there a need to put `abs` if you have `dnorm`? Shouldn't `dnorm` be non-negative?

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you; that's correct.  The `abs` is a vestige of an earlier (messier) incarnation of this formula (when it had been applied to `qnorm(x)`, which could be negative).  In my haste I did not remove it.

Answer (score 6):

This at least gives some pointers for - and a partial answer to - this question.

In the case of sample quantiles, the standard error depends on which definition of sample quantiles you actually use. I believe R, for example, includes 9 different definitions of quantiles in its `quantile` function.

For cases where the sample quantile is an exact order statistic, the standard error of the sample quantile follows from the standard error of that order statistic.

If a quantile is based on some weighted average of two order statistics, then the standard error can be obtained from [their variances, their covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution) and the weights.

As a result, [confidence intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution) can be formed; in the case of a quantile being an order statistic, a binomial distribution can be used to form a nonparametric interval directly from order statistics.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the problem of computing the standard error for sample quantiles of a normal distribution while attending a course of Quantitative Finance during my MSc. The main topic related to this problem regarded the analysis of Value at Risk.
This is the closed form solution:
$$
s.e.\left( \widehat{z}_{\alpha}\right)=\sigma \cdot \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n}} \cdot \sqrt{1+2z_{\alpha}^2\left( \dfrac{n-1}{2}-\dfrac{\Gamma^2(n/2)}{\Gamma^2((n-1)/2)} \right)}
$$
unfortunatly until now I can't provide you any reference for the proof.