# Monte Carlo simulation percentile convergence

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, convergence

Suppose I have a normal distribution random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I can easily calculate the 99.7 percentile, which $\approx\mu+3\sigma$.

In the Monte Carlo simulation of this random variable $X$, how could I find the convergence rate to 99.7 percentile? Say given a sample size $N$, what's the confidence interval for the simulated 99.7 percentile?

Comment: Which sample statistic are you computing? $\bar{x}+3s$ or some sample version of the 99.7 percentile? If the second thing, how are you defining your sample percentile

Comment: @Glen_b I think for a normal r.v. $\bar{x}+3s$ is 99.7 percentile, right? Let's define the problem for 99.7 percentile then.

Comment: For the normal distribution $\mu + 3\sigma$ is the 99.7 percentile, but for a sample from a normal the corresponding sample quantites are *not the same*, and they are not equally good (e.g. they have different mean square error). If you do want a sample quantile, *you have to define which one you mean*. For example, R has 9 different definitions for sample quantiles and that's not an exhaustive list of the definitions people have used (which definition you use can matter unless you're talking asymptotically).

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for your suggestions! Sorry but it confuses more. My question is how to find convergence rate for 99.7 sample percentile, given the most commonly used definition of percentile. Does it make the question clearer?

Comment: 1. I honestly don't know what the most commonly used definition of a sample percentile might be; I'd be quite surprised if anyone does (though some people may have opinions about what it might be). I'm not even sure how one could reasonably establish what the most commonly used definition is.  2. One thing that's a little unclear -- if you know for sure that your population is normal, why would you use an inefficient estimator of the desired population quantile?

Comment: @Glen_b Can I define the 99.7 percentile as the [0.997*n] th largest sample in n samples? Well the real problem I encountered is not normal distribution r.v.. I just simply want to know if there is a theorem to find the convergence rate for sample percentile, then I can extend my work.

Comment: Sample quantiles are typically weighted averages (or at least linear combinations) of adjacent [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic). There's a somewhat relevant answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110534/how-to-calculate-standard-error-of-sample-quantile-from-normal-distribution-with/
Approximate expectations, variances and covariances and (indeed, distributions of) order statistics may be obtained. Interior sample quantiles should have variance proportional to 1/n, if that's what you seek when you say "convergence rate"